# How need help to specify a grammar for arithmetic expressions

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, parsers

I am trying to come up with a grammar for arithmetic expressions with the following order of operations:

1. Parentheses
2. Factorials
3. Exponents
4. Functions / unary plus and minus
5. Juxtaposition (implied multiplication)
6. Multiplication and division
7. Addition and subtraction
8. Comma separated expressions

Functions should not require parenthesis, i.e. both `sqrt 2` and `sqrt(2)` are valid. Valid juxtapositions should be `<number> (<parenthesis> | <constant> | <function_expression>)`.

I can find plenty of examples of people who have created grammar for simple arithmetic that only includes binary operators and parenthesis. This is trivial, but when I try to expand it to included the previously stated items, it never works. I am not sure if the grammar I want is even specifiable in a non-ambiguous way, or if I am simply failing.

```
    <expression> ::= <add> ("," <add>)*
    <add> ::= <multiply> (("+" | "-") <multiply>)*
    <multiply> ::= <juxtapose> (("*" | "/") <juxtapose>)*
    
    ... no idea how to handle unary ops, functions, and juxtaposition
    as they seem to interact with each other ...

    <exponent> ::= <factorial> ("^" <exponent>)*
    <factorial> ::= <primary> ("!" | "!!")*
    <primary> ::= <number> | <constant> | <parenthesis>
    <parenthesis> ::= "(" <expression> ")"
```

Also, if you are unfamiliar with it, I found this useful site https://bnfplayground.pauliankline.com/

Edit: Here are some examples sentences:

- `-2^2` = `-(2 ^ 2)` Exp > Unary
- `2pi^2` = `2 * (pi ^ 2)` Exp > Juxtapose
- `2/2pi` = `2 / (2 * pi)` Juxtapose > Divide
- `2(3)` = `2 * 3`
- `2 sqrt 2` = `2 * sqrt(2)`
- `sqrt -2` = `sqrt(-2)`
- `sin 2pi` = `sin(2 * pi)`
- `atan pi, pi` = `(atan(pi), pi)`
- `atan(pi, pi)` = `atan(pi, pi)`

Comment: The question you ask might even be interesting, however it is difficult to devise a grammar generating the language you want. In my opinion you should show some sentences that exercize the non-standard features you want to include. For instance, I can't image how juxtaposition should work in the presence of other operations.

Comment: @Chaos Added some examples.

Comment: The language you are asking about is difficult to match using classic tools (lexer & parser). The sentences '2 sqrt 2' and 'sin 2pi' make the problem of recognizing the language very difficult because one would wonder how to distinguish between 'sin(2*pi)' and sin(2)*pi'. The fact you admit '2pi' to be a lexem as well as ' 2 pi' causes ambiguity, because it is unclear whether it represents a sequence of formal parameters to a function o a product that is also the single parameter. While for pi this might not be an issue, it is in general.

Comment: I think it is possible to match the language in question, but it would probably become a semantic analysis problem; that is, you read the input, trasform it into an abstract syntax tree and at that point you proceed to decide whether the input is well formed or abort.